# Is CoS supported in a logical system?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

This [reference](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.3/topics/concept/logical-systems-supported-features.html) states that class of service is supported in a logical system, but another [reference](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/junos/junos94/swconfig-policy/unsupported-configuration-statements-actions-and-action-modifiers.html) disagrees. This may be a disparity between versions, but I have notoiced there is no class of service stanza in a logical system on 12.3. Does the global CoS config apply to logical systems; will the following work as imagined?

```
set logical-systems prod interfaces ge-1/1/1 unit 0
set class-of-service interfaces ge-1/1/1 unit 0 rewrite-rules dscp default
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reference guide does state that configuring class of service on the main router will work for logical systems:

```
Port mirroring, source class usage, destination class usage, unicast reverse-path forwarding, 
class of service, firewall filters, class-based forwarding, and policy-based accounting work 
with logical systems when you configure these features on the main router.
```

So yes this will work as you expect.

This is similar to ipsec where you can only ipsec on the main router, but that still works within a logical system as I noted here: http://mellowd.co.uk/ccie/?p=3333

Comment: ACK. I'm guessing this is because each logical system starts new 'rpd' process, but they do not start new 'cos' process.

Comment: Seems I overlooked an important detail. Thanks!